# Проблема с бэкграундом сервлета

Tags: java, servlet

Есть сервлет, context root которого /servlet, urlPatterns - "/". То есть страница, с которой он работает, имеет вид: http://localhost:8080/servlet
У страницы html, которую он отображает, установлен `<body background="background.jpg">`, который не отображается что бы я ни делал. Однако если поставить в urlPatterns вместо "/", к примеру, "/index" и перейти по адресу http://localhost:8080/servlet/index - бэкграунд отображается как положено. Как сделать отображение бэкграунда и в первом варианте тоже?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, не используйте аттрибут `background` тега `<body>`, используйте CSS.

Во-вторых, ваша проблема  заключается в том, что запрос на получение файла `background.jpg` в первом случае проходит через ваш сервлет. В сервлете вы скорее всего не предусматриваете возможность отдавать статичные файлы ресурсов, поэтому при попытке доступа к ним вы получаете ошибку. Во втором случае запрос на получение файла `background.jpg` идёт в обход вашего сервлета, поэтому сервер успешно отдаёт этот файл.

Как это исправить? Во-первых, попробуйте сузить `url-pattern`, например, обрабатывайте только запросы к страницам `/*.jsp`. Во-вторых, создайте сервлет, отдающий статические ресурсы, или используйте `DefaltServlet`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`DefaultServlet` по умолчанию настроен отдавать любые файлы как статические, однако лучше будет ограничить его область действия одной папкой.

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Использование DefaultServlet для определенной папки решило проблему.